# Why trigger cms collect when 0K use in old generation when start jvm?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

When I start `jvm` (jdk 8) , I find this cms gc log . It shows old generation uses 0K (0K(1747648K)), but the jvm executes the cms collect . Why ?

```
2019-01-31T18:00:28.603+0800: 4.466: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 0K(1747648K)] 65577K(2534080K), 0.0077440 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
2019-01-31T18:00:28.611+0800: 4.474: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2019-01-31T18:00:28.627+0800: 4.490: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.016/0.016 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
2019-01-31T18:00:28.627+0800: 4.490: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2019-01-31T18:00:28.630+0800: 4.493: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.003/0.003 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
2019-01-31T18:00:28.630+0800: 4.493: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2019-01-31T18:00:29.748+0800: 5.611: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.824/1.117 secs] [Times: user=4.06 sys=0.13, real=1.12 secs] 
2019-01-31T18:00:29.749+0800: 5.612: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 437791 K (786432 K)]2019-01-31T18:00:29.749+0800: 5.612: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.2379222 secs]2019-01-31T18:00:29.987+0800: 5.850: [weak refs processing, 0.0000407 secs]2019-01-31T18:00:29.987+0800: 5.850: [class unloading, 0.0058594 secs]2019-01-31T18:00:29.993+0800: 5.856: [scrub symbol table, 0.0026897 secs]2019-01-31T18:00:29.995+0800: 5.858: [scrub string table, 0.0006242 secs][1 CMS-remark: 0K(1747648K)] 437791K(2534080K), 0.2489874 secs] [Times: user=0.96 sys=0.02, real=0.25 secs]
```

Below is my jvm option ：

```
 -server -Xms2560m -Xmx2560m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=52001 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=test 
  -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails 
  -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M
```

Comment: What are your GC options? If you have configured your IHOP incorrectly it could trigger old gen GCs simply by filling up the young one.

Comment: @the8472 see my update .

Comment: `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` makes no sense under Java 8. You should even see a warning in your logs that this option will be ignored. Further, `-server` is obsolete for 64 bit JVMs, as there is no other.

Comment: @Holger You are right , but it has nothing about this question .

Answer (score 0):

> It shows old generation uses 0K (0K(1747648K))

This is presumably due to the *initiating heap occupancy* heuristics settling on a really low value. Try setting setting it explicitly `-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=80 -XX+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly`, which will start one only when 80% of the heap is full.

Comment: It doesn't works  , when I set `-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=80 -XX+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly` , it still got this gc logs .

Answer (score 0):

What does -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution and -XX:+PrintGCCause give as cause?